# What's the proper way to generate dynamic routes for a social media app using Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, dynamic-routing

I'm building a social media app using Next.js + Sanity.

In a social media app, the data is in constant change as users add comments, likes, etc so it would make sense to use `getServerSideProps` for SSR since the data displayed should be updated on each request right?

But how can I handle the dynamic routes for let's say, a user's profile Page, a post, etc? The docs explain that for dynamic routes I should use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps` but that doesn't guarantee that the data for a user's profile or post will be updated since it's statically generated.

What's the proper way to work this out?

Comment: _"for dynamic routes I should use `getStaticPaths` and `getStaticProps`"_ - you can still use `getServerSideProps` for dynamic routes too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `getServerSideProps` gives you access to [the context parameter of that function](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#context-parameter) which will have a `params` property that contains your dynamic route. So for example, if you want to have a user's profile at `/user/{handle}`, you could create the following directory structure:

```
pages/
  user/
    [handle].js
```

Then in your `[handle].js` file (yes, the filename has square brackets), you would do something like this:

```js
export default function UserHandlePage({ handle }) {
  return (<p>Handle: ${handle}</p>)
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const userHandle = context.params.handle
  return {
    props: {
      handle: userHandle
    }
  }
}
```

You don't need to list out the paths - any visit to `/user/...` will run through that function. Also check out [Next Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes) documentation to see how to handle catch-all routes and other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle dynamic routes by adding brackets to the file inside the pages folder.

**for example you have a url of localhost:3000/ivanatias (ivanatias is your profile name)**

on pages directory

```
pages/
 [userProfileId].js
```

You can read more about [Dynamic Routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

now context.params.userProfileId will get the parameters on your url which would be **ivanatias**

now you can perform a fetch query on the database inside getServerSideProps and get the data with **userProfileId**

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const userProfileId = context.params.userProfileId
  const fakeFetch = await fetch(`someurl.com/profile/${userProfileId}`);
  const data = await fakeFetch.json();
  return {
    props: {
      data: data
    }
  }
}
```

now you can use the data on your component

for example

```
export default function profile({ data }) {
  return (<h2>{data.name}</h2>)
}
```

now regarding your question if you're gonna use getStaticProps or getServerSideProps. it's up to you if you think that the data doesn't change much often then probably you can use [ISG(Incremental Static Regeneration
)](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration)